# How to share master pages between Razor and Webforms

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, webforms

I asked this question before but the problem is I get one response and that response is not for the question that I asked. So, to make this clear, upfront, what this question is not about:

**I DO NOT WANT TO USE HYBRID, MVC and Webforms in the same project!**

Can someone provide me with a link that shows two projects running side-by-side with a single Master Page? One project is an ASP.Net Web Forms, containing the Master Page. The other project would be a MVC Razor project. The Master page would provide links to .aspx pages as well as .cshtml views. **Both these projects should be C#.** I need to be able to download the source code to see for myself how this all works.

**Answer #1 is not the answer that I am looking for. My question is very specific.**

Comment: Probably because the original Title is absolutely terrible.

Comment: It's easier to fix it...

Comment: @Nick K. you sound a litte bit rude, calm down. We are trying to help. If this is the second time you ask this and yet no one can understand, maybe you are not being so clear as you think.

Comment: This link is the closest to what I am after. This uses MvcContrib Portable Areas.This is a downloadable example, but this example uses VB.Net in the Asp.Net project and the MVC project is not Razor. http://trycatchfail.com/blog/post/Using-MVCContrib-glue-to-bring-Visual-Basic-WebForms-and-C-MVC-together.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know that's not possible for two reasons:

- You cannot use a .master page from outside the application. It must be part of the application (either as a file or as an embedded resource of a library combined with VirtualPathProvider trickery).
- You cannot use a .master page from .cshtml, just like you can't use a .cshtml layout file from an .aspx page as a MasterPageFile.

So re-using your existing .master page directly does not appear to be possible.

Comment: those are good points, but it's not true that it's not possible.  See http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MixingRazorViewsAndWebFormsMasterPagesWithASPNETMVC3.aspx

Comment: @Milimetric This still doesn't invalidate the first point (master must be local). AFAICT it also requires you to use an MVC master page, not just any old master page. Next, you'll need to change your controllers to return a different view result. The standard infrastructure in Razor views to use the Layout property to set a master no longer works, and you can't use `@sections` in your Razor view, so it limits the master to a single `<asp:Content>` element. So it's too limited for the question at hand. It's a nice hack none the less, one that can help you when you're in a bind.

Answer (score 2):

Since those are two different technologies, you won't be able to use the same *file*. You'll need to have a MasterPage for your WebForms application and a Layout for your MVC application that will look the same.

If your MasterPage/Layout doesn't have dynamic content and it's just plain html, I think you could have it in a file and create a script that creates both MasterPage and Layout files from it, but I don't think it worth it.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using layouts instead with MVC Razor.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/10/22/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I cannot show you the full sources. Not mine to show. But I can show you this. This is a partial that we use to render razor views using a WebForm Master page.

---razorview.aspx---

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <% Html.RenderPartial((string) ViewBag._ViewName); %>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="scriptContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="ScriptContent" runat="server">

</asp:Content>
```

---usage---

```
 public ActionResult Create(int clientId)
 {
....
return this.RazorView(choices);
```

---site.master(redacted)---

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage" %>

<%@ Import Namespace="...." %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Some Alt</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />   
    <link href="../../Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ScriptContent" runat="server" />
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="page">
        <div id="main">
            <table width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top" width="150" height="50">
                        <img src="<%= Common.CompanyLogoPath%>" alt="Some Alt width="150"
                            height="50" />
                    </td>
                    <td align="left" width="630" height="50" class="mainheading">
                        Description
                    </td>
                    <td align="right" valign="bottom">
                        <%= DateTime.Now.FormatShortDate() %>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3">
                        <hr />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top" class="rightBorder">
                        <table>
                           .....
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's not really using a Web Forms master page from a .cshtml MVC view, but rather using an MVC master page to display a partial.

Comment: the views being rendered are not partials, that are full razorviews. If anything is a partial its is razorview.aspx

Comment: Thinks like <asp.Content> and runat=server seems pretty WebForms to me. Could you provide a sample of how the MasterPage looks like, just to confirm?

Comment: @atbyrd Erm, aren't you calling RenderPartial? That looks suspiciously like rendering a partial. Anyway, how do you use this master page from a Razor view? Your razorview.aspx is not a Razor view (i.e., razorview.cshtml). The current setup is an ASPX MVC view calling a partial (which happens be a Razor view). The question is about using a Web Forms (not MVC) master as a layout for a Razor MVC view.

Comment: beautiful. Hey! I think here's your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Scott Hanselman as usual has a few options for this.  You can do it, but it's not pretty:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MixingRazorViewsAndWebFormsMasterPagesWithASPNETMVC3.aspx